Automating the Creation of an Excel Logbook
I Need help in Automating the Creation of an Excel Logbook
I have a folder on my OneDrive that contains multiple levels of sub-folders and various documents (PDFs, Word files, Excel sheets) within them. I want to create an Excel logbook with the following structure:

The first column should list the names of the main folders.
The second column should list the sub-folders within each main folder.
Subsequent columns should list further nested sub-folders or documents, continuing down to the deepest level.

Is there a method or tool that can automate this process without me manually ente?

You can of course automate this in a programming language of your choice. This question looks more like a coding question, which is better located on stackoverflow
